# Power losses in long wires with multiple loads

Tags: voltage, power, dc-dc-converter, wire, loss

I need to calculate power losses in long wires. I managed this for the case of constant currents. But in the real world, my loads are DC-DC regulators.

The load draws 11W of power, network voltage is 24V. So in ideal world DC-DC will draw about 0.5A from the network. But further from power supply voltage drop will increase -> voltage at load will decrease -> current have to increase. But voltage drop depends on current flow. And for me it looks like recursion.

[image]

Can somebody point me how to calculate such case?

Comment: If you want it exactly, you have to do the sums. A spreadsheet can be your friend, if you know the 'duplicate down' trick. Note that reducing input voltage into a DC-DC converter increases the current that it draws, if th eoutput stays at constant power. I have a mathematically minded friend who would probably say that 8 sections is near enough to infinity to approximate it via an integration. Not me, too likely to make an error that could not be spotted.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Now I'm curious. What's the 'duplicate down' trick?

Comment: @Transistor it's the only reason I'd use a spreadsheet rather than a computer language if I'm doing a small iteration problem. It works in all of libreoffice, msoffice, and google sheets. Select a cell with a formula in it, click on the 'block' in the bottom right hand corner, and drag down. All cell references get auto incremented. So to make a column of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 in A, put 1 in A1, =2*a1 in a2, then select a2 and drag the block down. Viola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model this in spice by using a voltage-dependent resistor or voltage-dependent current source as load.

For example, if a load draws 11W (including DC-DC losses) you can use a Function Current Source with the expression:

I = 11/max(12,V(node1,node2))

The nodes should be the two terminals of this specific load. Or you can use V(load).

The max() should prevent convergence problems, divisions by zero, and the like... however the input of a DC-DC still has negative resistance (current decreases with increasing voltage) thus it might not converge...

Comment: At the end LTSpice helped me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The choice Topology of series and/or parallel power feed determines what is best for bus load, and cable drop.

If your load is constant power or constant voltage or constant current, each must consider the accumulation of \$ I^2R=Pd \$ for cable losses.

Clearly the distribution R of the bus must be a low % of the load R for goid load regulation and efficiency, which you can calculate easily in a spreadsheet using Ohm's Law by R ratios or adding power losses or voltage drop.

Just like AC lines are designed for 5% distribution loss max with tap changers and prudent network design on power demand, you need to define a spec for bus regulation then choose a topology that suits your needs.

In the old days of distributed DC power both bulk power and DC reference voltages were fed to each line card for local regulation with the requirement that no designated feed current could be exceeded for the bus wire used.